# how to retrieve data from json string

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

```
[
  {
    "c_name" : "r",
    "email_id" : "r",
    "phn_no" : "2",
    "c_id" : "1"
  },
  {
    "c_name" : "e",
    "email_id" : "e",
    "phn_no" : "4",
    "c_id" : "2"
  }
]
```

This the output I received as JSON string. Now how can I access these data? I used `NSJSONSerialization` class:

```
NSError *writeError = nil;

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr_mcontacts options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"JSON Output: %@",jsonString);
```

Comment: You already had the data in the json.  It's what is in your `arr_mcontacts` before you serialized it as json.

Comment: There are literally hundreds and hundreds of past questions on how to parse json data using NSJSONSerialization. Out of all of these questions, which specific part in particular can you not understand how to do? What have you attempted to do so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an array of dictionaries. Something like this should work:

```
NSError *writeError;
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableArray *arrayOfDictionary = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
arrayOfDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

NSDictionary *dictionary = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *valueString= [dictionary objectForKey: @"c_name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

For accessing data you use a dictionary instead of string. The code below shows

`NSDictionary *responseDict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error]; for(NSArray *a in responseDict)
{[cnamearray addobject [a valueforKey:@"c_name"]];
}NSLog(@"The cnamearray contains:", cnamearray);`

The output will be       The cnamearray contains: { r,e}